# Android SlidingMenu add adapter to menu

Tags: android, android-menu

I am working with the [`Sliding Menu`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu&ei=jN_rUJOJNMmE4ASOoIC4BQ&usg=AFQjCNER7vbHLh9TiZOQ-uzShLNvJoP86A&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.bGE) and need a help from professional ! I want to add to menu(layout) with `ListView` adapter. I saw the demo app and it build at `Fragment`, but my app `extends SlidingActivity` and I can't understand how manipulate the `MenuView`

**MainActivity.class**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // MainView, MenuView
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    //SlidingMenu
    mMainMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_menu);
    mMenuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(this, R.id.menu_adapter_title);
    mMainMenu.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer it's work only with ArrayAdapter! 
If it help it's my code

```
private void populate() {

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_menu);
    String[] menu = {"Главная","Кино","Театры","Вечеринки","Концерты","Выставки","Рестораны","Магазины","Фотографии","Каталог","Погода"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.main_menu_adapter, R.id.menu_adapter_title, menu);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

and call it after `setBehindContentView`